# How to run click event by trigger in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have spent a lot of time on looking for answer and also try many solutions found here and on another websites. The problem is:

I have a click event assigned to some div element:

```
$('#xxx').on('click', function () {
    sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
});
```

And I want it to run automatically by itself on page start.
Everything is located into $(document).ready function.

I have tried:

- `$('#xxx').click();`
- `$('#xxx')[0].click();`
- `$('#xxx').trigger('click');`

Nothing helped. However, alert works when I manually click on this div on page.

Comment: What is body of `sweetAlert` ? Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some prechecks. Make sure:

1. The div you are binding to exists on the page (in this case, by the time the document ready event fires.
2. You are properly putting the binding before you fire it. If there are multiple document ready handlers, they will get called in the order they are processed on the page. To ensure that it is bound before calling, you can place both pieces of code in the same document ready handler. Note that $(function(){}) is short for $(document).ready(function(){});
3. Make sure that your "sweetAlert" function has been defined by the point that this is called, and test it. You can just call it in the document ready handler

**Finally, right after you bind the event you can trigger the event directly. See example below.**

Here is a working example for the given div. Note that I'm using alert here, but you can replace this with your "sweetAlert" or a jquery UI alert popup, or whatever else.

[JSFiddle for Chained Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/techdude/zembpqbg/)

```
<div id="clickMe">Click Me!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {//This is the document.ready
        $('#clickMe').click(function(){ //This binds the event
             alert("Something went wrong!");
        }).click(); //This fires it.
    });
</script>
```

Or if you prefer them separately,

[JSFiddle for Separate Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/techdude/qpzvmody/)

```
<div id="clickMe">Click Me!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {//This is the document.ready
        $('#clickMe').click(function(){ //This binds the event
             alert("Something went wrong!");
        });
        $('#clickMe').click(); //This fires it.
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Considering that you claim to have already done this, or something similar, I would recommend looking into the "sweetAlert" function and make sure it has been included before you try to call it.. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that is helped! Remember to upvote helpful answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the event handler (`$('#xxx').on('click', function () {`)

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
});
```

It will now run automatically on page load.

http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/pq2z2k13/10

Comment: Tried this, it do not fire this way.

Comment: Are you sure that sweetAlert is working? And could you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? @Dtg

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pq2z2k13/
You just need to add SweetAlert library there, I don't know how unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0):

Hear is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24ckmkr6/2/)

```
$("#xxx").click(function(){
```

Can be used instead of

```
$('#xxx').on('click', function () {
```